# dynamic import using forEach js es2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I am confident this isn't possible as well it doesn't work lol

I am using webpack with `babel-preset-es2015` & `babel-preset-react` and trying to dynamically build a form using data passed between the routes.

**Page loading < Form />**

```
        <Form data={
            [
                {
                    element: 'input',
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Jamie is Sex'
                },
                {
                    element: 'input',
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Jamie is Not Sex'
                },
                {
                    element: 'input',
                    type: 'password',
                    placeholder: 'Jamie is Not Sex'
                }
            ]
          }/>
```

**< Form /> / form.js**

```
    var buildElements = this.props.data.map(function (item) {
        var element = import item['type'] from './'+item['type'];
        return element;
    });
```

I realise I could do an if statement but I want it to rely on the filesystem. Maybe I need to check if the file exists with node.

Comment: No, this is not possible with ES2015: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340005/importing-modules-using-es6-syntax-and-dynamic-path
Have a look at webpack or browserify with CommonJS syntax instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like

```
const buildElements = this.props.data.map(item => require('./' + item.type));
```

Most javascript packers (webpack, rollup, and browserify) can understand this (non-ES6) syntax as well.