# How to automatically import and bundle JavaScript modules/files?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, redux, babeljs

Consider following file structure of JavaScript files of a [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) project (which is not that important but it's a real life scenario):

```
plugins/
  a/reducer.js
  b/reducer.js
  c/reducer.js
  rootReducer.js
```

This is the current content of `rootReducer.js`:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import a from './a/reducer'
import b from './b/reducer'
import c from './c/reducer'

export default combineReducers({ a, b, c });
```

Note that each of the `reducer.js` files *default exports* a reducer function.

To add a new plugin, I create an appropriate folder, add a new `reducer.js` file to it and then I need to manually import the reducer file and register it in `rootReducer.js`.

**I would like this process to be fully automatic.** I want the `rootReducer.js` file to go through all the subdirectories, look for a file `reducer.js` inside of them and eventually import it and add it to the root reducer using the folder name.

I'm using webpack and babel to compile and bundle my JavaScript files.

I know that there is a file system API in Node.js which would allow me to iterate through the folders and look for the `reducer.js` file. But is it going to work correctly once bundled with webpack? Is it safe to dynamically import modules/files?

Comment: [I'm afraid what you're asking for is impossible.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340005/importing-modules-using-es6-syntax-and-dynamic-path)

Comment: What about using `require`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to the following

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const DIR = __dirname + '/plugins';
const output = __dirname + '/plugins/rootReducer.js';

return fs.readdir(DIR, (err, files) => {
  let result = `import { combineReducers } from 'redux'\n`;
  let references = [];
  let reducers = files.filter(a => !a.includes('.'));

  reducers.forEach(reducer => {
    references.push(reducer);
    result += `import ${reducer} from './${reducer}/reducer'\n`;
  });

  result += `\nexport default combineReducers({ ${references} });\n`;
  fs.writeFile(output, result, err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(output + ' updated');
  });
});
```

Place this in your project directory and name it whatever you'd like. I'll call it reducersScript.js

From here you can either run it with node manually `node reducersScript.js` or hook it into your build process.