# Better way to import in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, es6-modules

In my project structure, I have some top level directories such as

```
components/
constants/
util/
test/, etc
```

I do the following when I have to import a module from `util` in `components/App`

```
import { formatDate } from '../../util/dateUtil'
```

This becomes cumbersome when modules are deeply nested. Is there a better way to do this? Something like:

```
import { formatDate } from '%BASE%/util/dateUtil'
```

Edit: I have used `webpack` as my module loader.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application

Comment: Would something like this not work? `const base = '/path/to/files/'; import { util } from base + '/util';`

Comment: This isn't so much a syntax question, the resolution of modules is up to the loader you are using. Are you using NodeJS, Webpack, Browserify, or similar? Each of those have their own solution to this problem

Comment: @evolutionxbox Unfortunately not. Syntax must be a string literal & statically analyzable

Comment: @CodingIntrigue - why doesn't string concatenation work?

Comment: I'm using Webpack. I'll try the solution mentioned by  @evolutionxbox

Comment: @CodingIntrigue is right. My solution won't work. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340005/importing-modules-using-es6-syntax-and-dynamic-path) will help

Comment: @evolutionxbox [The spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports) says a module specifier *must* be a string literal. I would imagine so that the JS engine can predetermine dependencies before runtime

Comment: @CodingIntrigue So it isn't possible then? Any way around it

Comment: @sanchit If you are using Webpack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502608/resolving-require-paths-with-webpack - either one of the top two answers