# Import dynamically all subfolders export

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, bundler

I have this:

```
-main.js
-routeDir
   -subfolder1
       -index.js
   -subfolder2
       -index.js
    ...       
    -subfolderN
       -index.js
```

the number of `subfolders` change according on some condition.
is there a way to import all `index.js` dynamically in my code in `main.js`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing modules using ES6 syntax and dynamic path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340005/importing-modules-using-es6-syntax-and-dynamic-path)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. ES6 modules need to be able to statically resolve their dependencies, without executing module code, so that `import` statements do work reliably. The module specifier must be a string literal.

However, the module loader of your choice should support dynamic loading of modules with variable names. You wouldn't be able to get a bound `app` identifier in your module scope however (and cannot reexport it), it typically would only be available in a callback or so.

[Importing modules using ES6 syntax and dynamic path [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30340066/4479618)