# Dynamic component path in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a divided my vuejs application in to components and whenever i update the architecture of the application, I need to change the component path wherever added. This makes the application maintenance difficult. So I have added the component path to settings.json file and with that I am trying to load the component. But this is not working. Please see the code below.

```
import Registration from platform.urls.uiComponent+'Account/Registration'
```

Does any one have any idea how to set dynamic component path in vuejs ?

Comment: What this great tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09n2945JW_0&t=2s

Answer (score -1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340005/importing-modules-using-es6-syntax-and-dynamic-path) it is not possible to do that. There is however an alternative way to achieve what you want to do if you use a tool such as webpack. In webpack configuration you can define an alias for a directory e.g. components, which you can use and afterwards change in a centralized location.